# Magento Integration Test failing

Tags: magento2, integration-test

I am running a suite of tests (integration tests) with Magento 2.
One test passes when it runs on its own and fails when it runs as part of the whole testsuite

the test uses a local fixture: @magentoDataFixture getMenuFixture

```
public static function getMenuFixture()
{
   require __DIR__.'/../_files/menu.php';
}
```

**success:**     php ../../../vendor/bin/phpunit ../../../app/code/Vendor/Module/Test/Integration/Controller/TopMenuTest.php

**failed:**    php ../../../vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite VendorCode

without great amount of experience with integration tests, I am hoping I can conclude the test I run requires being isolated to give same outcome when being ran on its own or as part of a suite.

To this end, I have attempted to add the following annotations:

- @magentoDbIsolation enabled
- @magentoAppIsolation enabled
- @magentoCache all disabled

I have also tried to debugged the data in the test database: I cannot see the fixture data in the database whilst the test runs and I understand that is because the integration test runs its fixture in a transaction operation that happens all in memory. Any ideas to debug this issue is welcome if it is not possible to diagnose the problem as the test codebase is obviously broad